# Bondi mass aspect

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, mass, resource-recommendations

I'm looking for a good reference that defines the Bondi mass aspect and his relations to Bondi and ADM mass.
Googling a bit I've not founded any satisfactory exposition of the subject.

A short explanation of the concept is welcome.

Answer (score 5):

The [living review on null congruences and asymptotic flatness](https://doi.org/10.12942/lrr-2012-1) is generally pretty spotty, but does contain a brief discussion of the mass aspect toward the end of Sec. 2.4.

On the most basic level, the mass aspect $\Psi$ is a function on $\mathscr{I}^+$ — that is, it depends on the retarded time $u$ and on the direction, usually given by the usual spherical angles $(\theta, \phi)$ or by the stereographic coordinate $\zeta$.  But if you go to a slice of $\mathscr{I}^+$ given by some particular retarded time $u$, it's just a function on the sphere.  The average value of this function is the Bondi mass, and its first moment is the Bondi momentum.  In the language of spherical harmonics, those are the $\ell=0$ and $\ell=1$ parts, respectively.

ADM quantities and Bondi quantities are different in very important ways.  In particular, ADM quantities measure aspects of the entire spacetime.  So, for example, the ADM mass measures the total mass in the entire universe, including any radiation, and so it never changes.  The Bondi quantities, on the other hand, are dynamical and time dependent, which can be useful for many purposes.

Another way of explaining the difference is to look at a Penrose diagram.  The ADM mass measures the mass on some spacelike slice, so that slice has to go to the sides of the diamond (labeled spacelike infinity).  The Bondi mass measures the mass on a slice of $\mathscr{I}^+$ (lightlike infinity), so it can change in time.  You could also say that Bondi mass is measured on an asymptotically null slice.

[image: Penrose diagram]

For example, imagine a binary black hole system that's not radiating much in gravitational waves at early times.  You can visualize it as sitting right in the middle of some early spacelike slice.  It then emits some intense waves as it merges, and those waves travel outward at the speed of light.  But that means they must intersect every future spacelike slice.  And since ADM measures on spacelike slices, that radiation will always be found somewhere on a slice, so its energy will always be included in the total mass.  But Bondi measures on asymptotically null slices, so the radiation might escape to $\mathscr{I}^+$, and its energy will not be counted.